# I can't do heroku push. ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I did `git push heroku master` then I got error below

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.example.com
```

So I did `heroku logs --tail` to find out the problems then I got below

```
enable Logplex by exmaple@mail.com
Release v2 created by example@mail.com
 Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby
```

I don't know how to fix this issue and push heroku well. need your help!

Comment: Can you provide more detailed account of the logs and what happens on `git push heroku master`?

Comment: 'remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected to myapp.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git''

Comment: Try searching with the error lines you're getting in the logs and on pushing to  heroku. I'm sure there are informative answers from the past that will guide you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure you've added

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

To your gem file and run

```
Bundle install
```

Followed by `git add .` and `git commit -am "something"`

And try to push again.

Comment: 'Counting objects: 149, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (134/134), done.
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 403
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (149/149), 42.07 MiB | 8.87 MiB/s, done.
Total 149 (delta 40), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date'

Comment: It would appear so. Can you check your app is running now on heroku?

Comment: Heroku | Welcome to your new app!
Refer to the documentation if you need help deploying.

Comment: My codes dose't appear though. What should I do to make them appeared?

Comment: It's possible it's just a glitch. Your code is getting pushed but it's not starting the server. Are you using posgresql in your app?

Comment: Best advice I can give now without seeing your code is to make sure you're following this guide. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4